# Http request failed for BizTalk Flat File Encoder in Logic App

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013, azure-logic-apps

I get the following error while trying to run a BizTalk Flat File Encoder?

> {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Http request failed: the timeout was reached."}

What is going wrong exactly? How do I debug it? Is something wrong with Azure itself or my schema for Flat File Encoder?

Answer (score 0):

The Flat File Encoder has a few dependencies, including uploading a Schema beforehand.  Check out the documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-flatfile-encoder/ let me know if that helps.